# Loading data from RDBMS to Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have an `App Engine` scheduled job which runs everyday and look for rows in a `PostgreSQL` table (hosted in gcp not a cloudsql) which meets a criteria to archive. If the criteria is met, it connects to `BigQuery` and streams the data to big query. Everyday there are few records qualify for archiving and we write to `BigQuery`. Is this the cost effective way or we can try loading data using `Cloud Functions`? https://cloud.google.com/solutions/performing-etl-from-relational-database-into-bigquery

Answer (score 0):

`App Engine` and `Cloud Functions` have different purposes. You should use App Engine if you want to deploy a full application in a serverless environment. If you need to integrate services in the cloud, use Cloud Function. In your case it seems that Cloud Functions fits better.

It's important to remember that Cloud Function has a time limitation: the maximum time which your code has to run is 9 minutes.
You can find this and other limitations [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas)

Furthermore, you can find [here](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/) a pricing calculator for `GCP` products.

If you have any further questions, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We will evaluate cloud functions for this purpose. I do not think  our code will run more than 9 mins. I will do some pricing calculation as well.

Comment: Ravi, please let me know if it was suitable for you